# Get the index number of elements relative to whole body not just relative to the nearest parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have found many questions and solutions on how doing this very basic thing in jQuery to get the index number.

```js
$(".container p").click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  alert(index);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
</div>
```

Ok, that's great, but obviously this is relative to `.container`.

How could I get the index relative to the whole page, so that if I had another `.container` half way up the page the index would still be counted for the next ones.

Make sense?

Comment: So if you had another `container` below the one you have, then the count shoud be 3,4,5 ?

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can provide a selector to `index()` for it to find the current element within, like this:

```js
$(".container p").click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index(".container p");
  console.log(index);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Six</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Seven</p>
  <p>Eight</p>
  <p>Nine</p>
</div>
```